# Slice string based on specific criteria

Tags: python

I am working on a set of strings like:

abc12b34aa
abc333333b
abd400s
wfd90a34aa

What I want to get out of these are:

12b34
333333
400
90a34

I want to take the first 3 digits which is easy to do in pandas Python
`df.suffix = df.name.str.slice(0, 3)`

What I am not sure of is how can I get to the base as mentioned above. The logic is that starting from end eliminate all until you get to the first number.

Comment: Can give give us some code, as a new user?  Thanks.  I already know the answer, but we here at stackoverflow want to see your attempt before assisting you in the answer.  Otherwise, we would be just doing your homework for you.

Comment: When you want to extract specific patterns from strings, the tool you want is regular expressions, not lines of code. If you want to continue learning about pattern extraction, I suggest learning about python's regular expression library. However, there are more important concepts for a new programmer to learn imo :)

Comment: You've properly analyzed the problem and described a solution.  What stops you from writing the code to implement the string search?  There's excellent documentation on string methods (e.g. `isdigit`) and `for` loops.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one!

```
def get_substr(string):
    for i in range(len(string)):
        if string[i].isdigit():
            break

    for j in range(len(string)-1, 0, -1):
        if string[j].isdigit():
            break
    return string[i:j]

df.name.apply(get_substr)
```

Comment: If I managed to help you, please consider marking my answer as accepted :D

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex:

```
import re
input = ['abc12b34aa', 'abc333333b', 'abd400s', 'wfd90a34aa']
for item in input:
    m = re.search(r'^\D*(.*?)\D*$', item)   # \D is any non-digit
    if m:
        result = m.group(1)
        print(result)
```

output:

```
# 12b34
# 333333
# 400
# 90a34
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass a list of chars into the `strip` method of a string and it will remove those chars from either end of the string. So since you want to remove all chars from either end until you get to a number. you can tell strip to remove all leading and trailing lowercase letters from your strings.

you can find find the document here for [str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/release/3.7.4/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=str%20split#str.strip)

```
import string

my_strings = """abc12b34aa
abc333333b
abd400s
wfd90a34aa"""

for line in my_strings.splitlines():
    print(line.strip(string.ascii_lowercase))
```

OUTPUT

```
12b34
333333
400
90a34
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a set of strings with numerics in it.  You essentially want to strip out all items in the string between (and including) the first and last occurrence of numbers.

Getting a list of indexes corresponding to numeric is as simple as:

```
x = "ajhdfg23,3bn,asd98af"
indices = [index for index, item for enumerate(x) if item.isdigit()]
if len(indices) < 1: return x // if you cant find a match, just return the base string.
low_value = indices[0]
max_value = indices[-1]+1
return x[low_value:max_value]
```

I wrote this so it was clean and concise so you could understand it, but you should be able to make it more compact:

```
x = "ajhdfg23,3bn,asd98af"
indices = [index for index, item for enumerate(x) if item.isdigit()]
return x if len(indices) == 0 else x[indices[0]:indices[-1]+1]
```